# Codeigniter i18n language causes $GET variables to get erased

Tags: codeigniter

Can't get codeigniter i18n language and $GET urls working when I use javascript to refresh to the following url

```
http://example.com/search?in=word&other=word2
```

it just goes to
`http://example.com/en/search` and the $GET variables get lost

my htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

what would be most elegant solution

//Part of `config/routes.php`

```
$route['^(en|fr)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
$route['^(en|fr)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Comment: Did you set the page as a special URL? In application/core/MY_Lang.php you can add search to the `$special` array to stop it being prefixed with a language. Check the Documentation, it's under the Options section - http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n

Comment: Yea, I am familiar with that option. However how do internationalize this page then if I disable it?

Comment: If you want to internationalize it then shouldn't the url be `http://example.com/en/search?in=word&other=word2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way I found was to do this in javascript, and just add the `lang` in my script

```
<script>
var lang="<?php echo $this->lang->lang(); ?>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line to include the query string as the rewrite rule drops that. See the [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Comment: nope, just tried it, I really think its the i18n language issue since it was working fine before I turned that on.

For example if I turn off i18n for that URL the (no /en/ or /fr/) the get variables get passed on fine

Answer (score 0):

I find the way, I add some changes in switch_uri function, so now my function look like this:

```
function switch_uri($lang)
  {
    if ((!empty($this->uri)) && (array_key_exists($lang, $this->languages)))
    {

        if ($uri_segment = $this->get_uri_lang($this->uri))
        {
            $uri_segment['parts'][0] = $lang;
            $uri = implode('/',$uri_segment['parts']);
        }
        else
        {
            $uri = $lang.'/'.$this->uri;
        }

        // Add $_GET string
        if (count($_GET) > 0)
            $uri .= '?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
    }

    return $uri;
  }
```